# 微分におけるゲーム数学と数学の違いについて知りたい。

Tags: c#, 数学

#### 質問内容

参考サイトの２つの動画ですがゲーム数学での微分は数学とはどう違うのでしょうか？
Unityエンジンの動画の`8:22`のところですが以下のことが知りたいです。

#### 知りたいこと

トライの動画等で微分の解き方を調べましたが`func(float x)`関数の意味がわかりません。なぜXの二乗を取る関数が必要なのでしょうか？

また、ゲーム数学上での微分の使われ方がどうやら数学とは違うみたいなのでそのあたりも知りたいです。

#### 調べたこと

ネット上で微分の解き方について調べました。

#### 参考サイト

[微分は傾き - ゲーム制作に使う数学を学習しよう #8 (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60NsGFP-B40&t=60s) (Unityエンジンの動画)
[【数学Ⅱ】第６章 微分法と積分法 コンプリート (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfOJcbz0N8NAoJpanifZtP6qSmttwh6Ts) (トライの動画)
[微分のやり方 (【微分のやり方】導関数の公式)参照](https://study-line.com/bibun-matome/)

```cs
using System;

public static class Program
{
    static float func(float x)
    {
        return x * x;
    }
    
    static float derivative(float x)
    {
        const float h = 0.1;
        return (func(x + h) - func(x)) / h;
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(derivative(3.0));
    }
}
```

Comment: 「なぜXの二乗を取る関数が必要なのでしょうか？」とのことですが、例としてその関数を定義されてるだけかと思います。それでは納得いかない理由がありますでしょうか？

Comment: 「ゲーム数学上での～」とか言われても意味が分からないのですが，まず「ゲーム数学」って何なのですか？（一般的に通じる語なのですか？　そのような何らかの体系(?)が存在するのでなければ質問自体が成り立たないように思うのですが）

Comment: @fana ゲーム開発で使われるような数学の基礎やその応用（実装など）を指して「ゲーム数学」と呼ばれることはあるように思います。英語だと math for game developers などと呼ばれている範囲に相当する認識です。無茶苦茶広く使われている語とは言えないと思いますが、意味が取れないほどではないなと思っていました。

Comment: 質問者の言い方ではまるで別の理論体系(?)のような物が存在するかのような印象を受けますが，「ゲームでよくつかう数学のはなし」程度のことなんでしょうかね？

Comment: 「ゲーム」というか「プログラム」では，関数`f(x)`の数式自体が存在しない場面でもその導関数（相当の概念）を考えたりすることはよくある……というのが「数式が出発点となる数学　との違い」と言えるのかも？

Comment: 例えば「壁にボールが当たったら跳ね返る」をやりたいときに，壁の衝突位置での法線が必要なのだとしよう．
「壁面」を表現するものが離散的な座標データの集まりでしかない場合，「衝突位置近隣のデータのみで構成される線とか面とかを考えてその法線を用いよう」とか（普通に/自然に）考えるよね．
これは数値微分（による近似）そのものだよね（壁面形状を「数式として」持っているならば法線とはその数式の導関数値そのものだ）．
多分，「ゲーム」ってのは特にそんな感じに離散データで物を表現することが多くて，そういうことをする機会が多い…ってだけなんじゃないかな．

Answer (score 4, accepted):

特にゲームを作る上での数学と普通の数学に差があるわけではありません。連続的に変化する値をコンピュータの上で表現するときに近似をしたくなることがあるという話です。

実数 x を与えると実数を返す関数 f について考えましょう。色々な解説で書かれているように、この関数 f を x で微分した関数 f' は、以下の式で定義できます。

[image: f'(x) = lim_{h → 0} (f(x+h) - f(x) / h]

ここで、数学的には微分の定義として極限 (lim) が必要になっているわけですが、この定義をそのままプログラムにしようとすると、プログラムの中のどこかで極限を計算しなければなりません。

よくあるプログラミング言語ではそういったことはできないので、別の方法で近似します。今回質問者さんが参考にされた動画では、`h` としてとても小さい値を使って右辺の分数を計算した値を使って、微分の値を近似しています。実際は `h` を `0` に近付けたときの極限を知りたいわけですが、それができないのでなるべく `0` に近い値で代用しているわけです。

ここで、いまこの微分の近似の計算を確かめるための例として f(x) = x² を選んでいるのは、おそらくそうすると分かりやすいからでしょう。今回の方法はもっと色々な関数に対して同じように使えるので、別に f(x) = x² にこだわる必要はありません。